# Fixed interval constraints in nlopt

Tags: c, nlopt

I am trying to implement an optimiser for a set of black-box functions (neural networks) for which I do not have a derivative (that's probably not relevant for this question though). I want to use `nlopt` so I've been reading through the tutorial on their website, which implements a trivial objective function with [Non linear constraints](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Tutorial#Example_nonlinearly_constrained_problem).

In their example, the constraint function is a set of continuously differentiable polynomials. The constraint arguably *is* the objective function in this example, which made the whole tutorial a bit confusing for a non-mathsy type such as myself. In my case I just want to impose fixed bounds on each dimension.

How do impose the fixed interval `[a,b]` on each dimension (and for an arbitrary number of dimensions) in `nlopt`?

I'm conscious of the fact that the constraint function in the tutorial also includes a derivative, and I'm not sure how or if I need to provide a derivative for my fixed interval constraint function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have read the whole tutorial...

`nlopt` provides the following functions specifically for the purpose of imposing fixed constraints:

`nlopt_set_lower_bounds`
`nlopt_set_upper_bounds`